# Get value changed in admin grid SaveButton magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, controllers, adminform, save

I created a custom magento 2 form.
As far as saving, I would like to take the modified value in the save.php of the controller.
Is there any method I can use?

This is my save.php controller

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

const ADMIN_RESOURCE = 'Index';

protected $resultPageFactory;
protected $contactFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    \Vendor\Module\Model\ProfileFactory $contactFactory
)
{
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->contactFactory = $contactFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

    $formKey = $data['form_key'];
    $data = $data['info']['manage_profile'];
    $data['form_key'] = $formKey;

    if($data)
    {
        try{

            $id = $data['profile_id'];

            $contact = $this->contactFactory->create()->load($id);

            $data = array_filter($data, function($value) {return $value !== ''; });

            $contact->setData($data);
            $contact->save();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__("Profilo {$data['name']} salvato con successo"));
            $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setFormData(false);
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        }
        catch(\Exception $d)
        {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setFormData($data);
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $contact->getId()]);
        }
    }

    return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
}
```

}

Instead of `$data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();`

I would like to use a method to get all the values modified in the form`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the changed data by adding this code before the `$contact->save()`.

```
$diff = array_diff_assoc($contact->getOrigData(), $contact->getData());
```

Comment: What I was looking for, thanks!